# ReadToEnd Works - ReadLine Doesn't

Tags: c#, readline

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ExtractData
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("test.txt");
      //string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
      string line = sr.ReadLine();
      sr.Close();
      while (line != null) ;
      Console.WriteLine(line);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be ? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proper way to read a file line by line :

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Once the `using` block ends the stream is closed automatically.

Comment: Could you explain how C# parses that line in the while loop? Specifically `while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)`; I don't understand how you can have an assignment statement, and then check for != null, all in one line. I've tried it and it works great, I just want to know why it works. @Dalmas

Answer (score 1):

Johni is right.  You want to do something like the following:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine (line);
  counter++;
}

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

sr.Close must be executed after reading the file and while needs to be around the write function:

```
while(){
   function();
}
```

If this line != null is ok with C# i'm not quite shure but i think there is a function in the StreamReader which can check for the end of the stream.

But it would be a good idea to learn the basic syntax of C#.

Answer (score 0):

sr.Close() closes the file stream.

The easiest way to read the lines is this:

```
string lines[] = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what is wrong with your code is that the value of line never changes which causes an infinite loop in your application. You also are not doing anything within the while loop.

I have corrected your code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ExtractData
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("test.txt");

      string line;
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      { Console.WriteLine(line); }

      sr.Close();
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would suggest (as mentioned by others) one of the following:

If it is a small file you could load the entire file into memory and work with it from there

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ExtractData
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("test.txt"))
      { Console.WriteLine(line); }

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, read the file line by line

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ExtractData
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
      {   
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        { Console.WriteLine(line); }
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Somehow, I came across this and didn't realise how old it was until I had posted the answer... Whoops :)